# rxJava create ArrayList from items

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Im trying to do the following:
1. Get Observables from ArrayList
2. Get name field from each item of this list
3. Create new ArrayList

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public Observable<Response<FriendsCheckResponse>> getFriendsInApp(String query) {
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.from(getContactList())
            .map(contactItem -> {
                test.add(contactItem.getNumber());
                return null;
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}
```

Comment: Why do you need an `Observable` for this? You can just do this with the stream-API: `getContactList().stream().map(contactItem -> contactItem.getNumber()).collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toList` to collect them into one `List`. There is no need for `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` in this case (plus `subscribeOn(immediate())` is functionally a no-op.

```
Observable<List<String>> numbers = Observable.from(getContactList())
    .map(v -> v.getNumber())
    .toList();
```